# How do i replace an image on load that only has a title attribute?

Tags: javascript

Lets say i have an Image in my html that has no id or class like:

```
<img title="me" src="something_blabla_nonactive">
```

and i want it to Change to

```
<img title="me" src="something_blabla_active">
```

when the page loads, how do i do that in JS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your options in order from the best to worst: 1. add id or class. 2. select image based on surrounding/parent elements. 3. select image by title attribute. The last one really sucks though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('img[title="me"]').attr("src", "something_blabla_activ")
```

Comment: This works great, but i just noticed that i have an mouseover image inside the img tag that needs to be changed as well, how do i do that?

`code`<img width="163" height="49" title="me" onmouseover="this.src=`hover.png'

Comment: Simply add    $( 'img[title="me"]' ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this )..attr("src", "something_blabla_hover-image");
  }, function() {
    $( this )..attr("src", "something_blabla_after-hover");
  }
);

Comment: That somehow doesnt work and breaks the first Code, too. Thats what i have now:
`code`
  jQuery('img[title="me"]').attr("src", "replaced.png");
 jQuery( 'img[title="BRANDImpact"]' ).hover( function() { $( this )..attr("src", "hover.png"); }, function() { $( this )..attr("src", "replacedhover"); } );

Also, i Need the same replace function for the mouseout handler which is also inside the img.

Comment: remove mouseover and mouseout from img.... and use $( 'img[title="me"]' ).hover( function() { $( this ).attr("src", "mouseover-image"); }, function() { $( this ).attr("src", "mouseout-image"); } );

Comment: I cant, because this is generated by a wordpress plugin that Shows Images instead of menu text. :-(
(The whole reason why i Need to replace Images is because i cant get Wordpress to set a specific menu item as active for Portfolio pages).

Comment: sorry for late...  $('img[title="me"]').attr({"src": "something_blabla_activ", "mouseover": " ", "mouseout": ""}) add this on page load then hover effect work

Comment: sorry for late as well, much apprecciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use `querySelector` to get the first one like this:

```
var firstImg = document.querySelector('img[title="me"]');
```

Or `querySelectorAll` to get an array-like object of all the images that have the title attribute set to `me` like this:

```
var allImgs = document.querySelectorAll('img[title="me"]');
```

The selector `[title="me"]` is the [**CSS Attribute-Equal Selector**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp), here is a reference of all [**CSS Selectors**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('img[title=blah]')
```

try this one.